# Gzip file but excluding some directories|files and also append current date

Tags: bash, shell, shell-script, compression, gzip

I'm looking for a way to create a `.tar.gz` file from a directory but I have some doubts. I'm know that the command for create the file is:

```
tar -zcvf /path/to/compressed/file.tar.gz /path/to/compress
```

And then I will get a `file.tar.gz` but this keep the path to the original sources. So this is what I'm looking for:

- Should be compress as `.tar.gz`
- If it's possible shouldn't keep the path to the compressed directory I mean I only needs the compress directory and its content .If I uncompress the file under Windows for example I'll get `/path[folder]/to[folder]/compress[folder+content]` and I just want the latest
- If it's possible can I ommit some directories? Example I like to compress `app/` folder and its content is:

  ```
  drwxrwxr-x  6 ubuntu ubuntu  4096 Feb 24 14:48 ./
  drwxr-xr-x 10 ubuntu ubuntu  4096 Feb 26 22:33 ../
  -rw-rw-r--  1 ubuntu ubuntu   141 Jan 29 06:07 AppCache.php
  -rw-rw-r--  1 ubuntu ubuntu  2040 Feb 24 14:48 AppKernel.php
  -rw-rw-r--  1 ubuntu ubuntu   267 Jan 29 06:07 autoload.php
  -rw-r--r--  1 root   root   94101 Feb 19 21:09 bootstrap.php.cache
  drwxrwxrwx  4 ubuntu ubuntu  4096 Feb 25 16:44 cache/
  -rw-rw-r--  1 ubuntu ubuntu  3958 Feb 24 14:48 check.php
  drwxrwxr-x  2 ubuntu ubuntu  4096 Feb 24 14:48 config/
  -rwxrwxr-x  1 ubuntu ubuntu   867 Jan 29 06:07 console*
  -rw-rw-r--  1 ubuntu ubuntu  6148 Jan 29 06:07 .DS_Store
  -rw-rw-r--  1 ubuntu ubuntu   143 Jan 29 06:07 .htaccess
  drwxrwxrwx  2 ubuntu ubuntu  4096 Feb 24 14:48 logs/
  -rw-rw-r--  1 ubuntu ubuntu  1118 Jan 29 06:07 phpunit.xml.dist
  drwxrwxr-x  5 ubuntu ubuntu  4096 Jan 29 06:07 Resources/
  -rw-rw-r--  1 ubuntu ubuntu 30404 Feb 24 14:48 SymfonyRequirements.php
  ```

  But I want to leave out `cache/`, `logs/` directories and `bootstrap.php.cache` file, how? Is that possible?
- I need to append the current date (DD/MM/YYYY-H:M:S) to the file name, how?

Can I  get some advise or help on this? I'm planning to add this to a Bash script so it will works as a bash script and not as a command line

**Update: testing inside the script**

Following **@Ariel** suggestion I have added this line to a bash script:

```
read -e -p "Enter the directory to compress: " -i "/var/www/html/" directory
read -e -p "Enter the filename: " filename
FILENAME = "$filename-`date +%d-%m-%Y-%X`.tgz"

cd "$directory"
tar -zcvf /home/$FILENAME --exclude cache --exclude logs --exclude bootstrap.php.cache --exclude composer.lock --exclude vendor
```

But I'm getting this error:

```
Enter the directory to compress: /var/www/html/lynxoft/apps/checkengine/
Enter the filename: checkengine
/usr/local/bin/script-task: line 109: FILENAME: command not found
tar: Cowardly refusing to create an empty archive
```

Why `FILENAME` is treat as a command and not as a var as [docs](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prog-Intro-HOWTO-5.html) says?

**Update 2: still compressing the whole path**

I have fixed some issues thanks to users comments and lines on the script looks likes this:

```
read -e -p "Enter the directory to compress: " -i "/var/www/html/" directory
read -e -p "Enter the filename: " filename
FILENAME="$filename"-$(date +%d-%m-%Y-%T).tgz

cd "$directory/.."
tar -zcvf /home/$FILENAME "$directory" --exclude="*cache*" --exclude=logs --exclude=bootstrap.php.cache --exclude=composer.lock --exclude=vendor --exclude=.git
```

The only remaining issue is that compressed file still having the whole path and not just the end directory. For example:

```
Enter the directory to compress: /var/www/html/lynxoft/apps/checkengine/
Enter the filename: file
```

That result in `file-28-02-2015-17:44:32.tgz` but content inside the compressed file still having the whole path `/var/www/html/lynxoft/apps/checkengine/`, why?

Comment: `tar -zcvf "/path/to/compressed/$(date +%d/%m/%Y-%X).tar.gz" -C /path/to/compress/ ./ --exclude="*cache*" --exclude=logs` (read **man tar**)

Comment: @Costas I've tried your solution also but get this `tar (child): /home/checkengine(date +%d/%m/%Y-%X).tar.gz: Cannot open: No such file or directory` error on console (also tried from the script) why?

Comment: You prolly forgot the `$` before `(date...)`. Also, @Costas - are you trying to create a file with `/`s in its name ?

Comment: @ReynierPM you should not leave spaces in the shell variable declarations!  Use exactly `FILENAME="..."`

Comment: @Ariel fixed that one but still getting this: `tar: Cowardly refusing to create an empty archive`

Comment: @ReynierPM it means that tar is not finding a single file to pack in the path you gave it... check your folders/paths. Actually, you forgot the path to "tar" at the very end of that command line: either add a . (a single dot, meaning everything in the current folder), a *, some filename or some subfolder you want to pack.

Comment: @Ariel thanks I have fixed that one too but one still, the related to path inside the compressed file can you take a look and point me in the right direction on this one as well?

Comment: @ReynierPM your tar command still contains an _absolute_ path: you use `tar -zcvf /home/$FILENAME "$directory" ...`   Change that to `tar -zcvf /home/$FILENAME . ...`   (seriously, a single dot, means "everything here")

Comment: Well, the dots are not very happily chosen, and also better quote the paths, sorry: 
`tar -zcvf "/home/$FILENAME" . --exclude="*cache*" <ETC>`

Comment: Actually i missed you point with the '.' You use `cd $directory/..`  so you should add:  `FOLDER=$(basename "$direcory")`  and then `tar  -zcvf "/home/$FILENAME" "$FOLDER" --exclude="*cache*" <ETC>`

Comment: You may use backticks instead of `$()`, i can't get them here inside code blocks. The command `basename` gives you the last part of the `$directory` path, so the forlder you want to compress as a relative path.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just `cd` to the folder from where you want the tarball tress structure to start, and use relative paths!
So for instance:

```
# Note, one folder above
cd /path/to/compress/..
# Tell tar to compress the relative path    
tar -zcvf /path/to/compressed/file.tar.gz compress
```

When you uncompress it, it will create the  `compress` folder in the current working directory.

You can exclude files or folders using the `--exclude <PATTERN>` option, and add a date in the filename with `date +FORMAT`, for instance:

```
FILENAME="file-`date +%d-%m-%Y-%T`.tgz"
tar -zcvf /path/to/compressed/$FILENAME --exclude cache --exclude logs --exclude bootstrap.php.cache compress
```

Comment: can you take a look to my latest edit?

Comment: Note that `%X = locale's time representation`; on some systems that means `11:43:11 AM`. So quote your variables (and preferably use `%T`).

Comment: @don_crissti did you see my latest edit? I have changed the `FILENAME` to `FILENAME = "$filename"-$(date +%d-%m-%Y-%T).tgz` but still getting the same issue `/usr/local/bin/script-task: line 109: FILENAME: command not found  tar: Cowardly refusing to create an empty archive` why? Any advice?

Comment: @don_crissti good point, i fixed my answer with that improvement now, thanks

Comment: @ReynierPM - wrong quoting. It's `tar -zcvf /path/to/compressed/"$FILENAME" ...` but then your `FILENAME="$filename"-$(date +%d-%m-%Y-%T).tgz` is wrong too, it has to be `FILENAME="$filename-$(date +%d-%m-%Y-%T).tgz"`... or if you want to include the date in the argument passed to `tar` see my answer.

Answer (score 2):

With `gnu tar` you could use:

```
--transform=EXPRESSION, --xform=EXPRESSION
      Use sed replace EXPRESSION to transform file names.
```

which means `--xform='s|path/to/||'` would remove `path/to/` from the path;
and

```
--exclude=PATTERN
      Exclude files matching PATTERN, a glob(3)-style wildcard pattern.
```

so you could run:

```
tar -zcvf /path/to/compressed/"$(date +%d-%m-%Y-%T)"-testdir.tar.gz \
--transform='s|^path/to/||' /path/to/compress \
--exclude='cache' --exclude='logs' --exclude='bootstrap.php.cache'
```

Note there's no leading `/` in the expression used with `xform`. A more generic approach:

```
--xform='s|^([^/]*/){2}||x'
```

That would strip the first two elements of the path (replace 2 with another number - as needed).

Comment: What would be the output of this one? The same but using another approach? If so valid too thanks

Comment: @ReynierPM - the output is as per your question. The difference when using `--xform` is that you don't have to `cd` to the parent directory & use relative paths. Only available with `gnu` `tar` afaik.